# Problem installing Ubuntu (cannot proceed, continue button disabled)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop which already has Windows 8.1 and CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503.
Basically I am trying to replace CentOS 7 with Ubuntu 15.10.

I swear, I started yesterday night and was looking at the screen to configure my disk partitions. I was not comfortable partitioning on Friday night, so I thought I will start next day morning.

Now today morning, I cannot get to the partitioning screen as the continue button is disabled. Since I could see the partitioning screen yesterday night, the DVD must be working correctly (I was not drunk I swear). How can a DVD go bad suddenly overnight. Any help or ideas what might be wrong?

See below screen shots where the continue button is disabled for both options - Erase Disk ... and Something else.

["Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tAHY.jpg)

["Something Else" option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f28hu.jpg)

Comment: you can try deleting the centos partition.  Do only if its useless.

Comment: Where do I delete it from? The screen which will allow me to delete is not coming up. I cannot delete CentOS partition by booting into CentOS I suppose.

Comment: choose "try ubuntu" instead of "install ubuntu " in the beginning. when ubuntu starts, use a software called `gnome-disks` to delete centos partition. Do this only if you are sure you dont require it because this will delete all the data.

Comment: I had booted into CentOS this morning before starting installation and opened Disks utility. I wonder if that utility has hold some sort of lock which is preventing me from moving ahead.

Comment: I don't think so..  You can also delete the centos partition from windows and try again.

Comment: Are you sure deleting CentOS partition won't corrupt my GRUB boot loader?

Comment: It will corrupt GRUB . but after the installation of ubuntu it will be reinstalled. (but only if ubuntu gets installed then ).